# How to bring down all internet devices except the specified one?

Tags: linux, command-line, ifconfig

I'm looking for a way to bring down all other devices except the given one.

I think it would be along the lines of greping the ifconfig output to then pull all the device names except the specified one and then use those names as input to an `ifconfig $DEV down` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ifconfig` is deprecated, use `ip` instead.

You can use this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
        echo "Device parameter missing!"
        exit 1
fi

devices=`ip a | grep UP | cut -d " " -f2 | tr -d ":" | grep -v "lo" | grep -v "$1"`

for dev in $devices
do      
        ifdown $dev
done
```

It is called as:

```
./script.sh <device>
```

For example with eth0:

```
./script.sh eth0
```

If called without parameter, reports `Device parameter missing!`.